# Java TicTacToe Game

Tags: java

I'm working on my assignment which is to create a TicTacToe checker, and for some reason I'm unable to think of a way to do the first steps of creating the game. We read in from a text file that contains a line which represents one game; for example:

```
x,x,o, , ,x, ,o,o
```

That would look like this on a traditional board:

```
x|x|o
-----
 | |x
-----
 |o|o
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
class TicTacToe{
    static String[][] game;

    public TicTacToe(int size){
        this.game = new String[size][size];
    }

    public static TicTacToe create(String input){
        String tokens = input.split(",");
        int size = (int)Math.sqrt(tokens.length); //For setting a size
                                                  // of the board

        return null;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how to return a new TicTacToe object: when I write my methods for checking rows, columns, etc. how will I get the board to check on? Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [W]hen I write my methods for checking rows, columns, etc. how will I
>   get the board to check on?

The instance of your object should contain all of the information about the board.  You have this (mostly) done already - `game` is the field which contains the information about the board.  The only catch is that *every* board will contain the same board information, and if it's updated, it will contain the updated information.

If you want to treat this like a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_2), then there are four things that you'll want to do:

- Remove the `static` modifier from `game`.  It's unnecessary and will lead to inconsistent states across multiple objects.
- Make your constructor private - unless I'm missing something, there's no reason to initialize it outside of the factory.

  ```
   private TicTacToe(int size) {
       game = new String[size][size];
   }
  ```

  Or, better yet:

  ```
   private TicTacToe(String[][] hydratedBoard) {
        game = hydratedBoard;
   }
  ```

  I'll show you why in a moment.
- Implement `TicTacToe.create(String)`, and return the fully hydrated object.  A suggestion would be to create the `String[][]` implicitly, create the object with that passed in as an argument to the constructor, and return your `TicTacToe` object.

  ```
  public static TicTacToe create(String input) {
      String[][] board = new String[3][3];
      int i = 0; // count the row we're on
      String[] tokens = input.split(",");
      for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
          if (j % 3 == 0) { // advanced to the end of the column set (SO)
              i++;
          }
          board[i][j] =  tokens[i*3 + j];
      }
      return new TicTacToe(board);
   }
  ```
- Provide some sort of getter to the board object.  You might not have to do this per the assignment, but it's good practice.  It could be either a straight-up getter on the `String[][]`, or some sort of pretty-print representation; I don't know.  I'll leave this implementation to the reader instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I was thrown an error on the line of setting a value to board[i][j], however I think that's because some of the inputted games from the text file aren't 3x3 boards. I got it to work though.

Comment: @user1327636 if they're not all 3x3 boards? Are they at least NxN? If the boards aren't square then how do you know the end of a row? Is the size of them explicitly provided?

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. Rather than "return null;", use "return new TicTacToe(size);".

Although, usually when I create a static factory method (like your "create" method) I make the constructor private so it can only be called from the static create method.

...and then you will need to update the board if you want to actually remember the x/o positions you passed in...

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely confusing myself. It's not necessary for our assignments to create a private and public method.

Answer (score 0):

Here I added an integration test for this game that might give you some ideas of how to create/think about the game.

```
    public void testWinnerPlayerIWithVerticalLine() {

    this.displayUnitTestDescription("Integration Test for having player 'X' as winner on a vertical line use case");
    final IBoardGame<TicTacToeMove, TicTacToePlayer> ticTacTocGame = new TicTacToeGame();
    final String playerIDisplayName = "X";
    final String playerIIDisplayName = "O";
    final TicTacToePlayer playerI = new TicTacToePlayer(playerIDisplayName);
    final TicTacToePlayer playerII = new TicTacToePlayer(playerIIDisplayName);
    ticTacTocGame.setGamePlayers(new TicTacToePlayer[]{playerI, playerII});
    TicTacToePlayer[][] expectedBoardInteractionSnapshot = new TicTacToePlayer[][]{
        new TicTacToePlayer[]{playerI,      null,       playerII},
        new TicTacToePlayer[]{playerI,      playerII,   null},
        new TicTacToePlayer[]{playerI,      playerII,   playerI}            
    };

    ticTacTocGame.start();
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(0, 0));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(1, 1));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(2, 2));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(0, 2));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(2, 0));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(2, 1));
    ticTacTocGame.makeMove(new TicTacToeMove(1, 0));

    this.displayBoardPlayerInteractionSnapshot(ticTacTocGame);
    final TicTacToePlayer[][] actualBoardInteractionSnapshot = ticTacTocGame.getPlayerInteractionSnapshotBoard();

    Assert.assertFalse(ticTacTocGame.isGameDraw());
    Assert.assertTrue(ticTacTocGame.existWinner());
    Assert.assertEquals(ticTacTocGame.getWinner().getDisplayName(), playerIDisplayName);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(actualBoardInteractionSnapshot, expectedBoardInteractionSnapshot);     
}
```

If you are interested to find out more you can find the whole java implementation of the TicTacToe game:  https://github.com/ncaralicea/tictactoe